# jquery boxy get a hidden div to show in the modal window

Tags: jquery, html, boxy

I am trying to just grab a div from the main page to show as the boxy modal content when i click a link. Right now it isnt working. The documentation for boxy is hard to digest.

Link HTML:

```
<div class="smClearBtn memberLinkBtn"><a title="Login" target="_blank"><span>Login</span></a></div>
```

jquery call:

```
$(".memberLinkBtn").click(function() {
   Boxy.get($("#popup_login"), {title: 'Login', modal: true});
});
```

what am i doing wrong? The click happens just the boxy is not working at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working?  Is it not doing anything, or doing something wrong?  Have you substantiated (through an `alert()` or whatnot) that the `click()` handler is firing?

Comment: The click happens just when it gets to the boxy call it does nothing at all. No error occur either in firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand from the documentation, the Boxy.get doesn't initialise a new Boxy instance but rather returns an already created instance:

```
Boxy.get(element)
Returns the Boxy instance containing element, e.g. <a href="#" onclick="Boxy.get(this).hide();">Close dialog</a>.
```

Try and create a new Boxy instance first, either automatically..

```
$("#popup_login").boxy();
```

.. or manually like this

```
new Boxy("<p>Content</p>", {title: "Dialog"});
```

Reference: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

Comment: Yah i was looking into too and found that. I tried this way too and it still did nothing. It is strange to me that this would be so complicated. I don't know... maybe i need to choose a different modal. Thank you for the response though!